# How is "scone" pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation

> Scone (skɒn,skəʊn) *noun*: a small unsweetened or lightly sweetened cake made from flour, fat, and milk and sometimes having added fruit

How is this pronounced? Some people say s *co* ne and some people say sc *on* e. Is there any evidence that suggests that either is the correct way to pronounce this word? If not, Is there a way which suggests how to say it depending on your location?

Comment: It depends on the variety of English. In the UK, it rhymes with con, and in the US, with cone. http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2013/03/how-do-you-say-scone/

Comment: In either case the final "*e*" is not pronounced, unless you have a German accent.

Answer (score 5):

There is a complex pattern of variation. In the British isles this is regional, and class based. The Unversity of Cambridge did [research on this](http://www.cam.ac.uk/research/news/cambridge-app-maps-decline-in-regional-diversity-of-english-dialects). The orange areas show where "scone" rhymes with "gone", in blue areas, scone rhymes with "cone", and in yellow areas both pronunciations are common.

[image]

As an English learner you can be confident that both pronunciations are known and accepted. You should use whichever you prefer.

Comment: I can confirm this, growing up near Stoke-on-Trent "scone" was pronounced to rhyme with "cone", however my family (originally from north Wales) pronounced it to rhyme with "gone".